# Signing up Codewars

Tags: java

I'm trying to get an account in [Codewars](http://www.codewars.com) and was surprised you have to show them you have some basic knowledge in one of the programming languages offered. I chose Java but got stuck in one the exercises. The code is:

```
public class Person {
    String name;

    public Person(String personName) {
        name = personName;
    }

    public String greet(String yourName) {
        return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", yourName, name);
    }
}
```

It says, "Correct this code, so that the greet function returns the expected value". The thing is, I do not see the error and in fact I copied the code to Eclipse and after changin the Java compiler and use version 1.6 the code works, no error and if you try it with a main method it returns the expected value.

If only they tell you which the expected value is... When submitting, no matter what I try I always get "The code does not work as expected".

Any ideas?

Comment: Yeah you should do `return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", name, yourName);`. The code they give is syntactically right but they expect you greet the other way.

Comment: No words... hahahaa. Thanks a lot man!

Comment: I suspect they want you to swap the values in the `String.format()`, though it's pretty ambiguous.  The method doesn't specify if this is you greeting the person or the person greeting you...

Comment: Frankly, I think the OP is correct. The OO metaphor for calling a function on an object with an argument is "tell the object to perform the action on the object". In other words, if the object is Jim, then Jim.greet("Joe") is telling Jim to greet Joe, and "Hi, Joe, my name is Jim" is the right thing to do.

Comment: @AlexisC. Please tell me that isn't. Who wants to join such group if the entrance question is that f... up?!

Comment: @Hannes Well, you can try :) http://www.codewars.com/?language=java

Comment: I completely agree with you David. Anyway, I'll take a look at the website, a friend recommended it. Thank you all

Comment: Wow, have to agree with @Hannes,  THIS is the criteria for entrance?  No thank you!

Comment: FWIW, these "code captchas" are intended to be anti-robot, not anti-human measures. This particular challenge is no longer being used in favor of a much less ambiguous debugging kata.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You are correct; this code is correct as written, and the Codewars guys are boneheads. They probably want you to switch the names around the other way.

The OO metaphor for calling a function on an object and passing an argument is "tell the object to perform the action on the given object". In other words, if the object is `Jim`, then `Jim.greet("Joe")` is telling Jim to greet Joe, and "Hi, Joe, my name is Jim" is the right thing to do.

Actually, since greeting is really a communication between two persons, the real correct thing to do is not to pass a string name to `greet`, but to pass a `Person`, and have `greet` call that `Person`'s `beGreeted()` method.

Comment: Agree. Questions like this are terrible.

Answer (score 1):

The Answer Is : Justyou need two swap the variables in String.format().

Question:

return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", name, yourName);

Answer :

return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", yourName, name);

```
 public class Person
 {
     String name;
     public Person(String personName){
     name = personName;
     }
     public String greet(String yourName)
      {
         return String.format("Hi %s, my name is %s", yourName,name);
       }
  }
```